# Should we amend the tags in the main site

Tags: discussion

Should we add information about this site on the Sitecore tags of StackOverflow to let people know we are here?

Comment: That is a good question for the admins of Stack Exchange. I think we would have to wait till public beta.

Comment: @ASURA As an admin of Stack Exchange, I responded  below: http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/95/6

Answer (score 4):

In reality we simply have no cause to solicit content from Stack Overflow by usurping a part of their scope to *this* site. Sitecore programming is still on topic on Stack Overflow, so (before it comes up), please do *not* solicit content or users by posting in tags or in comments on Stack Overflow; that is not allowed.

See [Respect the community - your own, **and others’**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) (emphasis mine)

Comment: Is this still considered poor form after we leave beta?

Comment: @DanSolovay Yes, it's poor form, beta or not. Unless a question has been deemed off topic for that site, you shouldn't be soliciting users and on-topic questions away from one site into your own.

Comment: Thank you Robert.

Comment: I agree StackOverflow is a valid and correct place to ask for programming questions related to Sitecore. If the question is not strictly programming related or within SO guidelines then I have seen `Close > Off-Topic > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network`. Would this site be added to that list for questions that are tagged with `Sitecore` on SO?

Comment: @jammykam It's up to each community to decide which sites they pick for their migration paths, but those sites would have to [graduate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) before becoming eligible.

Answer (score 0):

As ASURA explains, its probably a good thing to wait before we go public. And when we do, there will still be users favoring StackOverflow for a while, before realizing that there are better answer on this community.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the link provided by @Robert Cartaino I understand we shouldn't edit the tags, but if we see questions related to Sitecore where we think could be resolved by our site, it's Ok to add a comment suggesting to ask it here once we are generally available.

Comment: Worth reading Roberts answer again. It states "or in comments".

Comment: That's why I created my own answer. My understanding of that post is that it's ok to suggest to visit this site on the comments (in fact I have seen other similar comments suggesting posting a question in a different site)

Comment: Maybe this refers to sites that are not in beta?

Comment: @Anicho, Good point, I'll update my answer with it